# Age Bracket Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdown, the first dropdown compose of age from 18 to 60. My problem is, what I want for my 2nd dropdown is that, for example if the user selects from the first dropdown is 20, the second dropdown most compose of 21-60. Is it possible?

Here's my code, (I'm using javascript to loop the range)

```
<select  name="sab"  class="req"  id="age-range" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select> -
<select  name="eab"  class="req"   style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var $select = $("#age-range");
    for (i=18;i<=60;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<select  name="sab"  class="req"  id="age-range" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select> -
<select  name="eab"  class="req"  id="second" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $("#age-range");
    for (i=18;i<=60;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }

    $("#age-range").change(function(){
        var val = parseInt($("#age-range").val());
        $("#second").html("");
        for(i=val+1; i<=60; i++) {
            $("#second").append("<option value='" + i + "'>"+i+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j32gL6mj/

Like this?

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible that in the first dropdown, that the default display is blank?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but just add an empty option and add an if statement to see if isnt 0, then do the for loop.

Comment: I dont get it, haha sorry no sleep, can you try implementing it to the fiddle please? :D I;m very sorry

Comment: Once again, sorry for the late answer :( Sleep and work :( But here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/j32gL6mj/1/